# Gitlab: How to use artifacts in subsequent jobs after build

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I've been trying to make a GitLab CI/CD pipeline for deploying my MEAN application. I have three stages:
1. test
2. build 
3. deploy

The build stage has a build_angular job which generates an artifact. Now I want to use this artifacts in the next stage i.e deploy. 
The deploy job tells me that it has downloaded the artifact(image has been attached), but now I want to extract this artifact, but I don't know where the artifact is being downloaded.

The path where the artifact is being downloaded is not mentioned anywhere in the docs.
[image: if]

Answer (score 44):

GitLab is cleaning the working directory between two subsequent jobs. That's why you have to use `artifacts` and `dependencies` to pass files between jobs.

When the "deploy" job says that the build artifact have been downloaded, it simply means that they have been recreated as they were before. The location of the downloaded artifacts matches the location of the artifact paths (as declared in the .yml file).

#### Example

```
build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "create bin/ directory"
  - make
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bin/

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - ls bin/
  dependencies:
  - build_job
```

Directory `bin/` is passed to `deploy_job` from `build_job`.

Comment: It seems to be also important that the jobs which build the artifacts are on prior stages (which is already the case here).

Comment: What if you had steps: build, test, and deploy? For deploy I want to get the artifacts from the build step, not the test step. Otherwise I'd be deploying stuff like test-coverage.xml.

Answer (score 3):

If the artifact is downloaded, it will be situated at the very same path it was in the task it was registered. Thus, **if you cannot find an artifact then it is likely not being downloaded.**

To make sure you get an artifact from a specific task, you have two options:

1. Using [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs) (as of GitLab 12.2)
2. Using [`dependencies`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#dependencies)

*Using `dependencies` is well explained by [@piarston's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56731740/1622937), so I won't repeat this here.*

With the newer `needs` keyword you can even explicitly specify if you want the artifacts or not. This is done by means of the [`needs:artifacts`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needsartifacts) keyword:

```yaml
build_job:
  stage: build
  script:
  - echo "create bin/ directory"
  - make
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bin/

deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - ls bin/
  needs:
  - job: build_job
    artifacts: true

other_job:
  stage: deploy
  needs:
  - job: build_job
    artifacts: false
```

In this example, the artifacts are downloaded for the `deploy_job` but not for the `other_job`.

With [`needs`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#needs) you can write explicitly and in a clear manner where you need the artifacts, and where you just want to wait for the previous job to finish.

Comment: how to reference artifact in Dockerfile?

Comment: you can simply copy `bin/` to the docker, something like `FROM something/something

COPY ./bin /usr/share/bin`

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`gitlab-org/gitlab-runner` issue 2656](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2656) mentions:

> > But the documentation talks about this limitation in fact : "in the latest pipeline that succeeded" : no way now to get artifacts from the currently running pipeline.
>
> Thank you !
>   I think the documentation should really make it more obvious that you need the whole pipeline to complete before the artifact is accessible and that you can't use this within the pipeline.
>
> It seemed to me that the obvious usecase of this feature would be deploying on the server, and that you'd want server deployment to be part of the pipeline.

That comes from [Pipelines / Jobs Artifacts / Downloading the latest artifacts](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-artifacts)

> To download a single file from the artifacts use the following URL:
>
> ```
> https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/raw/<path_to_file>?job=<job_name>
> ```

See [`allpix-squared/allpix-squared`](https://gitlab.cern.ch/allpix-squared/allpix-squared/commit/edd3c1c124e3b0b1dff780ae71f03be762b73c17) as an example.

Its [`.gitlab-ci.yml` deploy stage](https://gitlab.cern.ch/allpix-squared/allpix-squared/commit/edd3c1c124e3b0b1dff780ae71f03be762b73c17#587d266bb27a4dc3022bbed44dfa19849df3044c_520_608) calls a script with the right path:

> ```
> sudo -u cvclicdp -i $RUNNER_LOCATION/.gitlab-ci.d/gitlab_deploy.sh $RUNNER_LOCATION $BUILD_PATH
> ```

Comment: What do you have to say about the deploy jobs which does show that it has downloaded the artifact?

Comment: @GoutamBSeervi I have added an example which shows that you can trigger the download in any folder you want.

Answer (score -4):

Each job runs on the separate runner.

[Upload artifact action implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIqV8.png)

Github Action "**actions/upload-artifact@v3**" uploads the files from provided path to storage container location.

In next job when you run action "**actions/download-artifact@v3**" , it downloads the artifact from 'storage container location' where previous job uploaded the artifacts to provided path.

[Implementation for download artifact and displaying download path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usTKO.png)

For more information refer below links,

[Github action for upload artifacts](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)

[Github action for download artifacts](https://github.com/actions/download-artifact)

Comment: Question is related to gitlab not github.